How to get the First N values of multiple columns?
Let's say I have the following table:
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, "Phone" AS product, 105 AS cost UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, "Camera" AS product, 82 AS cost UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, "Cup" AS product, 103 AS cost
) SELECT * FROM tbl

How would I get N distinct values for each column? For example, similar to the "Value distribution" (bottom right) from Power BI shown here:

I don't care about the counts of each value, but just to pull a representative sample of values (say, up to ten values).
For example, to display a sample of values without having to run a query for each column? That is, I'd like to grab them all in one-go. So far I have something like:
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'Phone' AS product, 105 AS cost UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 'Camera' AS product, 82 AS cost UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, 'Cup' AS product, 103 AS cost
) 
SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT id LIMIT 2),
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT product LIMIT 2),
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT cost LIMIT 2)
FROM tbl

This works, but it seems very inefficient (I believe the same as running a query for each column). What is a better way to do this?
Or, to generalize what I think to be a poor approach but applicable outside BQ:
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'Phone' AS product, 105 AS cost UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 'Camera' AS product, 82 AS cost UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, 'Cup' AS product, 103 AS cost
)  
select 'id' as field, array(select distinct cast(id as string) from tbl limit 2) as values union all
select 'product', array(select distinct cast(product as string) from tbl limit 2) union all
select 'cost', array(select distinct cast(cost as string) from tbl limit 2);

And a further improvement based on Mikhail's answer:
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, "Phone" AS product, 105 AS cost, true as is_big, date '2014-01-01' as d UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, "Camera" AS product, 82 AS cost, false as is_big, date '2017-01-01' as d UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, "Cup" AS product, 103 AS cost, false as is_big, date '2015-01-01' as d union all
    SELECT 7 AS id, "Several" AS product, 103 AS cost, true as is_big, date '2016-01-01' as d
) 
SELECT 
  name, 
  IF(
    array_length(quantiles) is not null, 
    ARRAY(SELECT CAST(tmp AS STRING) FROM UNNEST(quantiles) tmp), 
    ARRAY(SELECT value FROM t.top_values)
  ) values
FROM ML.DESCRIBE_DATA(
  (SELECT * FROM tbl), STRUCT(3 AS num_quantiles, 4 AS top_k)
) t;


If the order doesn't matter, then you could group per column and use ROW_NUMBER to pick row numbers < N.
Another solution is to SELECT DISTINCT on a single column. It'll still be more efficient than your current solution of SELECT .. ORDER BY .. UNION ALL.

@Omkar sounds good. Want to show that in an answer then -- the order doesn't matter so you can use the row_number.

Does it have to be distinct 100 values? Then first approach is reasonably good.

The first option is the best, if you can remove DISTINCT

@Charlieface what if the first 100 values are all null then? I want to get a sample of values, such as (any) 100 of them.

A skip scan with a recursive cte would do exactly what you want, exactly how you want it: run just once and iteratively grab values that haven't already been collected, until it collects your desired number of distinct samples for each column. PostgreSQL has it, BigQuery has it too.
On 300k random rows with 3 columns holding 1k, 190 and 10k unique values respectively, it takes 0.12ms to get 3 samples, 1.2ms to get 30, 40.0ms to get 120 of each, with no index: demo at db<>fiddle
prepare recursive_cte_3way_skip_scan(int) as 
with recursive cte as (
( select   1 as i
          , array[id] ids 
          , array[product] products
          , array[cost] costs
  from tbl limit 1) --get 1 random, most convenient value
  union all
  select cte.i+1 as i
       ,  (select array[id] ids 
           from tbl 
           where array_position(cte.ids,tbl.id) is null 
           limit 1) ||cte.ids
       ,  (select array[product] products 
           from tbl 
           where array_position(cte.products,tbl.product) is null
           limit 1) ||cte.products
       ,  (select array[cost] costs 
           from tbl 
           where array_position(cte.costs,tbl.cost) is null
           limit 1) ||cte.costs
  from cte where $1>i
) 
select ids, products, costs
from cte order by i desc limit 1;

I'm using array_position() instead of <>all() to be able to catch null values. The latter uses regular equality = so it will never look for or match against them. The former uses is not distinct from construct instead, so it can handle them fine.



ids
products
costs




{94,937,743}
{"Mouse Pad",Floor,Fork}
{213.9,64.3,362.5}



You could come up with a scenario where your assumption isn't correct:

This works, but it seems very inefficient (I believe the same as running a query for each column).

Having "a query for each column" could actually be desired if you have indexes on them. PostgreSQL will split it up into 3 independent InitPlans against the 3 indexes, popping your desired number of examples from each of them.
In the same test, it takes 0.9ms, and since this is just taking N steps up a BTree, you can expect this to scale linearly relative to the target sample size of N, regardless of how big your data set is:
create index idx1 on tbl (id);
create index idx2 on tbl (product);
create index idx3 on tbl (cost);
vacuum analyze tbl;

prepare subqueries_three as
select (select array_agg(id) from (select distinct id from tbl limit 3)_)
      ,(select array_agg(product) from (select distinct product from tbl limit 3)_)
      ,(select array_agg(cost) from (select distinct cost from tbl limit 3)_);

explain analyze verbose execute subqueries_three ;
execute subqueries_three;




QUERY PLAN




Result  (cost=126.35..126.36 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.829..0.831 rows=1 loops=1)


  Output: $0, $1, $2


  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)


                      ->  Index Only Scan using idx1 on public.tbl  (cost=0.42..5724.42 rows=300000 width=4) (actual time=0.041..0.081 rows=430 loops=1)


                            Output: tbl.id


  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)


                      ->  Index Only Scan using idx2 on public.tbl tbl_1  (cost=0.42..5772.42 rows=300000 width=8) (actual time=0.034..0.365 rows=3155 loops=1)


                            Output: tbl_1.product


  InitPlan 3 (returns $2)


                      ->  Index Only Scan using idx3 on public.tbl tbl_2  (cost=0.42..8000.42 rows=300000 width=6) (actual time=0.037..0.043 rows=54 loops=1)


                            Output: tbl_2.cost


Planning Time: 1.046 ms


Execution Time: 0.900 ms






array_agg
array_agg
array_agg




{0,1,2}
{"Air Freshener",Apple,Bag}
{0.0,0.1,0.2}



Still, if you do have the indexes set up, you can remix the skip scan earlier into an index skip scan. It's the 3rd one down in the demo, the quickest one of them all, grabbing the 120 samples in 5ms.
Probing a data set with no indexes in place is exactly what tablesample, already mentioned by @Erwin Brandstetter, was made for. The fact that distinct only has to go through a small portion of the table can save most of the work.
The exec time is driven by that sample size - if you lower it too much you increase the risk the slice you get doesn't happen to have your desired number of examples:
SELECT 
    (ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT id))[:3],
    (ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT product))[:3],
    (ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT cost))[:3]
FROM tbl tablesample system(.1) ;




QUERY PLAN




Aggregate  (cost=26.35..26.36 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.467..0.468 rows=1 loops=1)


  Output: (array_agg(DISTINCT id))[:3], (array_agg(DISTINCT product))[:3], (array_agg(DISTINCT cost))[:3]


  ->  Sort  (cost=23.34..24.09 rows=300 width=18) (actual time=0.119..0.138 rows=321 loops=1)


        Output: id, product, cost


        Sort Key: tbl.id


        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 39kB


        ->  Sample Scan on public.tbl  (cost=0.00..11.00 rows=300 width=18) (actual time=0.013..0.061 rows=321 loops=1)


              Output: id, product, cost


              Sampling: system ('0.1'::real)


Planning Time: 0.092 ms


Execution Time: 0.494 ms






array_agg
array_agg
array_agg




{10,15,33}
{"Air Freshener",Apple,Bag}
{0.03,1.27,1.42}



With indexes, the index skip scan can still perform comparably, without the risk of hitting a non-representative slice or the need to tweak the parameter.
Without them, as long as your values are evenly distributed or you're lucky, that's the simplest way to speed things up.

Consider below as an option (BigQuery) - fast and cheap and have no dependency on number of columns!!
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, "Phone" AS product, 105 AS cost UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, "Camera" AS product, 82 AS cost UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, "Cup" AS product, 103 AS cost
) 
SELECT name, quantiles AS num_values, ARRAY(SELECT value FROM t.top_values) AS string_values
FROM ML.DESCRIBE_DATA(
  (SELECT * FROM tbl),
  STRUCT(1 AS num_quantiles, 2 AS top_k)
) t;



pretty cool. Want to explain how that works, especially the cross join at the end. Also, I believe num_quantiles should be N-1 and top_k should be N. Is that correct? very cool!

Exactly! you can see full spec here - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-describe-data

By the way, I've added (to my question) an improvement that puts the values in a single column. There is one problem though...the arrays don't allow null values, which is usually a huge problem in unknown data (that often has a lot of null values!) It's a shame that BQ has that limit on the array types! I swear, that is my biggest complaint out of everything with BQ (and the issue I run into the most).

Your question leaves room for interpretation. You mention "first", but don't define it. Your query has DISTINCT without mentioning anything about that earlier. Your sample shows neither null values nor duplicates, it's unclear how to deal with those.
Using a subquery in Postgres, this runs a single, very cheap sequential scan and stops at the small LIMIT:
SELECT array_agg(id)      AS ids
     , array_agg(product) AS products
     , array_agg(cost)    AS costs
FROM  (
   SELECT id, product, cost 
   FROM   tbl
   -- no ORDER BY, take arbitrary rows cheaply
   LIMIT  2
   ) sub;

A more representative sample can be had with the "ordered-set aggregate function" percentile_disc(). Like:
SELECT percentile_disc('{0,.5,1}'::float[]) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id)      AS pctl_id
     , percentile_disc('{0,.5,1}'::float[]) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product) AS pctl_product   
     , percentile_disc('{0,.5,1}'::float[]) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cost)    AS pctl_cost
FROM   tbl;

This variant of percentile_disc() takes float8[] - an array of percentages - and picks a column value at each given percentage within the defined sort order. Rather sophisticated. You can pick any number of column values from any position in the sort order.
This way, you can chose where in the sort order and how many values to pick from each column, while still scanning the table once.
Or, for big tables, based on a small semi-random sample to make it cheaper (while less representative):
SELECT percentile_disc('{0,.5,1}'::float[]) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS pctl_id
     , ...
FROM   tbl  TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (10);

fiddle
percentile_disc() ignores null values, array_agg() includes them.
Duplicates get no special treatment (yet) in any of these. Any combination of these features (and more) is possible to optimize for performance, randomness, uniqueness, validity, ...
You just need to define exactly what you need.
See:

Fast way to discover the row count of a table in PostgreSQL
Can someone give examples of use case of the ordered-set functions in PostgreSQL 9.4?

BigQuery seems to only provide the variant of percentile_disc() getting a single value.

thanks for the detailed answer Erwin, I've updated the question with more details and a screenshot of what I'm looking to do / inspiration for why.

My answer is mostly for Postgres (as tagged). You seem to be using BQ after all ...

I'm using both for testing (actually I need to connect to both -- Postgres locally and BQ remotely).

Approx_top_count gives up to 200 uniques per item?
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate_aggregate_functions#approx_top_count

If the target table isn't completely fresh (PostgreSQL collected some stats on it, or you ran analyze), then you can grab most_common_vals from pg_stats system view: db<>fiddle demo
select attname as column_name
      ,(most_common_vals::text::text[])[:5] as sample
from pg_stats
where tablename='tbl';




column_name
sample




id
{866,77,760,812,419}


product
{"Rubber Band",Bread,Twister,"Model Car",Knife}


cost
{430.0,960.5,474.8,575.3,705.8}



You get it in constant time since it's routinely pre-fetched by the db on its own - you just re-use what's already there.
It's an anyarray which can't be subscripted or cast directly, which is why I go through its text representation first. Then, [:5] gets a slice of the first 5 elements. The view also offers most_common_freqs that shows what % of rows these values correspond to, so you can upgrade any-N to top-N value sampling, for free.

If you want more samples than the db collects on its own, you can adjust that on column or global level.
